# Can std::future cause coredump without get or wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future, coredump

```
void func() {
    std::future<int> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, []{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        return 8; 
    });
    return;
}
```

Let's say that I have such a function. An object `fut` of `std::future<int>` is initialized with a `std::async` job, which will return an integer in the future. But the `fut` will be immediately released after the function `func` returns.

Is there such an issue: When the `std::async` job returns and try to assign the `8` to the object `fut`, the object has already been released...

If so, a coredump about SIGSEGV may occur...

Am I right about it? Or `std::future` has some mechanism to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Futures created with `std::async` have a blocking destructor that waits for the task to finish.

Even if you instead create a future from `std::promise`, the docs for [`~future()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) don't mention the problem you're asking about.

The docs use the term "shared state" a lot, implying that a promise and a future share a (heap-allocated?) state, which holds the return value, and isn't destroyed until both die.